# Generating 10 random numbers in a range in an awk script

Tags: awk

So I'm trying to write an awk script that generates passwords given random names inputted from a .csv file. I'm aiming to do first 3 letters of last name, number of characters in the fourth field, then a random number between 1-200 after a space. So far I've got the letters and num of characters fine, but am having a hard time getting the syntax in my for loop to work for the random numbers. Here is an example of the input:

```
Danette,Suche,Female,"Kingfisher, malachite"
Corny,Chitty,Male,"Seal, southern elephant"
```

And desired output:

```
 Suc21 80
 Chi23 101
```

For 10 rows total. My code looks like this:

```
BEGIN{
FS=",";OFS=","
 }
{print substr($2,0,3)length($4)

 for(i=0;i<10;i++){
 echo $(( $RANDOM % 200 ))
}}
```

Then I've been running it like

```
awk -F"," -f script.awk file.csv
```

But it only shows the 3 characters and length of fourth field, no random numbers. If anyone's able to point out where I'm screwing up it would be much appreciated , thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rand()` to generate a random number between 0 and 1:

```
awk -F, '{print substr($2,0,3)length($4),int(rand()*200)+1}' file.csv
```

Comment: awk -F, 'BEGIN{srand();}{print substr($2,0,3)length($4),int(rand()*200)+1}'           CAUTION: In most awk implementations, including gawk, rand() starts generating numbers from the same starting number, or seed, each time you run awk.45 Thus, a program generates the same results each time you run it. The numbers are random within one awk run but predictable from run to run. This is convenient for debugging, but if you want a program to do different things each time it is used, you must change the seed to a value that is different in each run. To do this, use srand().

Answer (score 0):

```
BEGIN{
FS=",";OFS=","
 }
{print substr($2,0,3)length($4)

 for(i=0;i<10;i++){
 echo $(( $RANDOM % 200 ))
}}
```

There is not `echo` function defined in GNU `AWK`, if you wish to use shell command you might use [`system`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/I_002fO-Functions.html) function, however keep in mind that it does return status code and does print what said command output, without ability to alter it, so you need to design command so you get desired output from it.

Let `file.txt` content be

```
A
B
C
```

then

```
awk '{printf "%s ",$0;system("echo ${RANDOM}%200 | bc")}' file.txt
```

might give output

```
A 95
B 139
C 1
```

Explanation: firstly I use `printf` so no newline is appended automatically, I output whole line followed by space, then I execute command which does output random value in range

```
echo ${RANDOM}%200 | bc
```

it does simply ram RANDOM followed by `%200` into calculator, which does output result of such action.

If you are not dead set on using `RANDOM` variable, then [`rand`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Numeric-Functions.html) function, might be use without hassle.

*(tested with gawk 4.2.1 and bc 1.07.1)*

Answer (score 0):

just a quick note : there are noticeable `awk` peculiarities when `substr()` indices are less than 1 :

```
for ___  in $( jot 6 -3 ); do
for ____ in $( jot 9 ) ''; do 
for __   in 'mawk1' 'mawk2'  'gawk -e' 'gawk -Pe' 'gawk -ce' 'nawk'; do

  echo 123456789 | $( printf '%s' "$__" ) '{
    
  printf(" %10s | substr($0, %2d%4s) == \42%s\42\n",
               __, ___, (_<____ ? ", " : _)____, 
          _<____ ? substr($+_, ___, ____) \
                 : substr($+_, ___)) }' __="$__" ___="$___" ____="$____"

done; done; done | rs -t -c$'\n' -C'_' 0 2 | column -s'_' -t | lgp3 6
```

---

```
      mawk1 | substr($0, -3 , 1) == "1234"             mawk1 | substr($0,  0 , 1) == "1"
      mawk2 | substr($0, -3 , 1) == ""                 mawk2 | substr($0,  0 , 1) == ""
    gawk -e | substr($0, -3 , 1) == "1"              gawk -e | substr($0,  0 , 1) == "1"
   gawk -Pe | substr($0, -3 , 1) == "1"             gawk -Pe | substr($0,  0 , 1) == "1"
   gawk -ce | substr($0, -3 , 1) == "1"             gawk -ce | substr($0,  0 , 1) == "1"
       nawk | substr($0, -3 , 1) == "1"                 nawk | substr($0,  0 , 1) == "1"
```

---

```
      mawk1 | substr($0, -3 , 2) == "12345"            mawk1 | substr($0,  0 , 2) == "12"
      mawk2 | substr($0, -3 , 2) == ""                 mawk2 | substr($0,  0 , 2) == "1"
    gawk -e | substr($0, -3 , 2) == "12"             gawk -e | substr($0,  0 , 2) == "12"
   gawk -Pe | substr($0, -3 , 2) == "12"            gawk -Pe | substr($0,  0 , 2) == "12"
   gawk -ce | substr($0, -3 , 2) == "12"            gawk -ce | substr($0,  0 , 2) == "12"
       nawk | substr($0, -3 , 2) == "12"                nawk | substr($0,  0 , 2) == "12"
```

---

```
      mawk1 | substr($0, -3 , 3) == "123456"           mawk1 | substr($0,  0 , 3) == "123"
      mawk2 | substr($0, -3 , 3) == ""                 mawk2 | substr($0,  0 , 3) == "12"
    gawk -e | substr($0, -3 , 3) == "123"            gawk -e | substr($0,  0 , 3) == "123"
   gawk -Pe | substr($0, -3 , 3) == "123"           gawk -Pe | substr($0,  0 , 3) == "123"
   gawk -ce | substr($0, -3 , 3) == "123"           gawk -ce | substr($0,  0 , 3) == "123"
       nawk | substr($0, -3 , 3) == "123"               nawk | substr($0,  0 , 3) == "123"
```

---

```
      mawk1 | substr($0, -3 , 4) == "1234567"          mawk1 | substr($0,  0 , 4) == "1234"
      mawk2 | substr($0, -3 , 4) == ""                 mawk2 | substr($0,  0 , 4) == "123"
    gawk -e | substr($0, -3 , 4) == "1234"           gawk -e | substr($0,  0 , 4) == "1234"
   gawk -Pe | substr($0, -3 , 4) == "1234"          gawk -Pe | substr($0,  0 , 4) == "1234"
   gawk -ce | substr($0, -3 , 4) == "1234"          gawk -ce | substr($0,  0 , 4) == "1234"
       nawk | substr($0, -3 , 4) == "1234"              nawk | substr($0,  0 , 4) == "1234"
```

---

```
      mawk1 | substr($0, -3 , 5) == "12345678"         mawk1 | substr($0,  0 , 5) == "12345"
      mawk2 | substr($0, -3 , 5) == "1"                mawk2 | substr($0,  0 , 5) == "1234"
    gawk -e | substr($0, -3 , 5) == "12345"          gawk -e | substr($0,  0 , 5) == "12345"
   gawk -Pe | substr($0, -3 , 5) == "12345"         gawk -Pe | substr($0,  0 , 5) == "12345"
   gawk -ce | substr($0, -3 , 5) == "12345"         gawk -ce | substr($0,  0 , 5) == "12345"
       nawk | substr($0, -3 , 5) == "12345"             nawk | substr($0,  0 , 5) == "12345"
```

---

```
      mawk1 | substr($0, -3 , 6) == "123456789"        mawk1 | substr($0,  0 , 6) == "123456"
      mawk2 | substr($0, -3 , 6) == "12"               mawk2 | substr($0,  0 , 6) == "12345"
    gawk -e | substr($0, -3 , 6) == "123456"         gawk -e | substr($0,  0 , 6) == "123456"
   gawk -Pe | substr($0, -3 , 6) == "123456"        gawk -Pe | substr($0,  0 , 6) == "123456"
   gawk -ce | substr($0, -3 , 6) == "123456"        gawk -ce | substr($0,  0 , 6) == "123456"
       nawk | substr($0, -3 , 6) == "123456"            nawk | substr($0,  0 , 6) == "123456"
```

---

```
      mawk1 | substr($0, -3 , 7) == "123456789"        mawk1 | substr($0,  0 , 7) == "1234567"
      mawk2 | substr($0, -3 , 7) == "123"              mawk2 | substr($0,  0 , 7) == "123456"
    gawk -e | substr($0, -3 , 7) == "1234567"        gawk -e | substr($0,  0 , 7) == "1234567"
   gawk -Pe | substr($0, -3 , 7) == "1234567"       gawk -Pe | substr($0,  0 , 7) == "1234567"
   gawk -ce | substr($0, -3 , 7) == "1234567"       gawk -ce | substr($0,  0 , 7) == "1234567"
       nawk | substr($0, -3 , 7) == "1234567"           nawk | substr($0,  0 , 7) == "1234567"
```

---

```
      mawk1 | substr($0, -3 , 8) == "123456789"        mawk1 | substr($0,  0 , 8) == "12345678"
      mawk2 | substr($0, -3 , 8) == "1234"             mawk2 | substr($0,  0 , 8) == "1234567"
    gawk -e | substr($0, -3 , 8) == "12345678"       gawk -e | substr($0,  0 , 8) == "12345678"
   gawk -Pe | substr($0, -3 , 8) == "12345678"      gawk -Pe | substr($0,  0 , 8) == "12345678"
   gawk -ce | substr($0, -3 , 8) == "12345678"      gawk -ce | substr($0,  0 , 8) == "12345678"
       nawk | substr($0, -3 , 8) == "12345678"          nawk | substr($0,  0 , 8) == "12345678"
```

---

```
      mawk1 | substr($0, -3 , 9) == "123456789"        mawk1 | substr($0,  0 , 9) == "123456789"
      mawk2 | substr($0, -3 , 9) == "12345"            mawk2 | substr($0,  0 , 9) == "12345678"
    gawk -e | substr($0, -3 , 9) == "123456789"      gawk -e | substr($0,  0 , 9) == "123456789"
   gawk -Pe | substr($0, -3 , 9) == "123456789"     gawk -Pe | substr($0,  0 , 9) == "123456789"
   gawk -ce | substr($0, -3 , 9) == "123456789"     gawk -ce | substr($0,  0 , 9) == "123456789"
       nawk | substr($0, -3 , 9) == "123456789"         nawk | substr($0,  0 , 9) == "123456789"
```

---

```
      mawk1 | substr($0, -3    ) == "123456789"        mawk1 | substr($0,  0    ) == "123456789"
      mawk2 | substr($0, -3    ) == "123456789"        mawk2 | substr($0,  0    ) == "123456789"
    gawk -e | substr($0, -3    ) == "123456789"      gawk -e | substr($0,  0    ) == "123456789"
   gawk -Pe | substr($0, -3    ) == "123456789"     gawk -Pe | substr($0,  0    ) == "123456789"
   gawk -ce | substr($0, -3    ) == "123456789"     gawk -ce | substr($0,  0    ) == "123456789"
       nawk | substr($0, -3    ) == "123456789"         nawk | substr($0,  0    ) == "123456789"
```

---

```
      mawk1 | substr($0, -2 , 1) == "123"              mawk1 | substr($0,  1 , 1) == "1"
      mawk2 | substr($0, -2 , 1) == ""                 mawk2 | substr($0,  1 , 1) == "1"
    gawk -e | substr($0, -2 , 1) == "1"              gawk -e | substr($0,  1 , 1) == "1"
   gawk -Pe | substr($0, -2 , 1) == "1"             gawk -Pe | substr($0,  1 , 1) == "1"
   gawk -ce | substr($0, -2 , 1) == "1"             gawk -ce | substr($0,  1 , 1) == "1"
       nawk | substr($0, -2 , 1) == "1"                 nawk | substr($0,  1 , 1) == "1"
```

---

```
      mawk1 | substr($0, -2 , 2) == "1234"             mawk1 | substr($0,  1 , 2) == "12"
      mawk2 | substr($0, -2 , 2) == ""                 mawk2 | substr($0,  1 , 2) == "12"
    gawk -e | substr($0, -2 , 2) == "12"             gawk -e | substr($0,  1 , 2) == "12"
   gawk -Pe | substr($0, -2 , 2) == "12"            gawk -Pe | substr($0,  1 , 2) == "12"
   gawk -ce | substr($0, -2 , 2) == "12"            gawk -ce | substr($0,  1 , 2) == "12"
       nawk | substr($0, -2 , 2) == "12"                nawk | substr($0,  1 , 2) == "12"
```

---

```
      mawk1 | substr($0, -2 , 3) == "12345"            mawk1 | substr($0,  1 , 3) == "123"
      mawk2 | substr($0, -2 , 3) == ""                 mawk2 | substr($0,  1 , 3) == "123"
    gawk -e | substr($0, -2 , 3) == "123"            gawk -e | substr($0,  1 , 3) == "123"
   gawk -Pe | substr($0, -2 , 3) == "123"           gawk -Pe | substr($0,  1 , 3) == "123"
   gawk -ce | substr($0, -2 , 3) == "123"           gawk -ce | substr($0,  1 , 3) == "123"
       nawk | substr($0, -2 , 3) == "123"               nawk | substr($0,  1 , 3) == "123"
```

---

```
      mawk1 | substr($0, -2 , 4) == "123456"           mawk1 | substr($0,  1 , 4) == "1234"
      mawk2 | substr($0, -2 , 4) == "1"                mawk2 | substr($0,  1 , 4) == "1234"
    gawk -e | substr($0, -2 , 4) == "1234"           gawk -e | substr($0,  1 , 4) == "1234"
   gawk -Pe | substr($0, -2 , 4) == "1234"          gawk -Pe | substr($0,  1 , 4) == "1234"
   gawk -ce | substr($0, -2 , 4) == "1234"          gawk -ce | substr($0,  1 , 4) == "1234"
       nawk | substr($0, -2 , 4) == "1234"              nawk | substr($0,  1 , 4) == "1234"
```

---

```
      mawk1 | substr($0, -2 , 5) == "1234567"          mawk1 | substr($0,  1 , 5) == "12345"
      mawk2 | substr($0, -2 , 5) == "12"               mawk2 | substr($0,  1 , 5) == "12345"
    gawk -e | substr($0, -2 , 5) == "12345"          gawk -e | substr($0,  1 , 5) == "12345"
   gawk -Pe | substr($0, -2 , 5) == "12345"         gawk -Pe | substr($0,  1 , 5) == "12345"
   gawk -ce | substr($0, -2 , 5) == "12345"         gawk -ce | substr($0,  1 , 5) == "12345"
       nawk | substr($0, -2 , 5) == "12345"             nawk | substr($0,  1 , 5) == "12345"
```

---

```
      mawk1 | substr($0, -2 , 6) == "12345678"         mawk1 | substr($0,  1 , 6) == "123456"
      mawk2 | substr($0, -2 , 6) == "123"              mawk2 | substr($0,  1 , 6) == "123456"
    gawk -e | substr($0, -2 , 6) == "123456"         gawk -e | substr($0,  1 , 6) == "123456"
   gawk -Pe | substr($0, -2 , 6) == "123456"        gawk -Pe | substr($0,  1 , 6) == "123456"
   gawk -ce | substr($0, -2 , 6) == "123456"        gawk -ce | substr($0,  1 , 6) == "123456"
       nawk | substr($0, -2 , 6) == "123456"            nawk | substr($0,  1 , 6) == "123456"
```

---

```
      mawk1 | substr($0, -2 , 7) == "123456789"        mawk1 | substr($0,  1 , 7) == "1234567"
      mawk2 | substr($0, -2 , 7) == "1234"             mawk2 | substr($0,  1 , 7) == "1234567"
    gawk -e | substr($0, -2 , 7) == "1234567"        gawk -e | substr($0,  1 , 7) == "1234567"
   gawk -Pe | substr($0, -2 , 7) == "1234567"       gawk -Pe | substr($0,  1 , 7) == "1234567"
   gawk -ce | substr($0, -2 , 7) == "1234567"       gawk -ce | substr($0,  1 , 7) == "1234567"
       nawk | substr($0, -2 , 7) == "1234567"           nawk | substr($0,  1 , 7) == "1234567"
```

---

```
      mawk1 | substr($0, -2 , 8) == "123456789"        mawk1 | substr($0,  1 , 8) == "12345678"
      mawk2 | substr($0, -2 , 8) == "12345"            mawk2 | substr($0,  1 , 8) == "12345678"
    gawk -e | substr($0, -2 , 8) == "12345678"       gawk -e | substr($0,  1 , 8) == "12345678"
   gawk -Pe | substr($0, -2 , 8) == "12345678"      gawk -Pe | substr($0,  1 , 8) == "12345678"
   gawk -ce | substr($0, -2 , 8) == "12345678"      gawk -ce | substr($0,  1 , 8) == "12345678"
       nawk | substr($0, -2 , 8) == "12345678"          nawk | substr($0,  1 , 8) == "12345678"
```

---

```
      mawk1 | substr($0, -2 , 9) == "123456789"        mawk1 | substr($0,  1 , 9) == "123456789"
      mawk2 | substr($0, -2 , 9) == "123456"           mawk2 | substr($0,  1 , 9) == "123456789"
    gawk -e | substr($0, -2 , 9) == "123456789"      gawk -e | substr($0,  1 , 9) == "123456789"
   gawk -Pe | substr($0, -2 , 9) == "123456789"     gawk -Pe | substr($0,  1 , 9) == "123456789"
   gawk -ce | substr($0, -2 , 9) == "123456789"     gawk -ce | substr($0,  1 , 9) == "123456789"
       nawk | substr($0, -2 , 9) == "123456789"         nawk | substr($0,  1 , 9) == "123456789"
```

---

```
      mawk1 | substr($0, -2    ) == "123456789"        mawk1 | substr($0,  1    ) == "123456789"
      mawk2 | substr($0, -2    ) == "123456789"        mawk2 | substr($0,  1    ) == "123456789"
    gawk -e | substr($0, -2    ) == "123456789"      gawk -e | substr($0,  1    ) == "123456789"
   gawk -Pe | substr($0, -2    ) == "123456789"     gawk -Pe | substr($0,  1    ) == "123456789"
   gawk -ce | substr($0, -2    ) == "123456789"     gawk -ce | substr($0,  1    ) == "123456789"
       nawk | substr($0, -2    ) == "123456789"         nawk | substr($0,  1    ) == "123456789"
```

---

```
      mawk1 | substr($0, -1 , 1) == "12"               mawk1 | substr($0,  2 , 1) == "2"
      mawk2 | substr($0, -1 , 1) == ""                 mawk2 | substr($0,  2 , 1) == "2"
    gawk -e | substr($0, -1 , 1) == "1"              gawk -e | substr($0,  2 , 1) == "2"
   gawk -Pe | substr($0, -1 , 1) == "1"             gawk -Pe | substr($0,  2 , 1) == "2"
   gawk -ce | substr($0, -1 , 1) == "1"             gawk -ce | substr($0,  2 , 1) == "2"
       nawk | substr($0, -1 , 1) == "1"                 nawk | substr($0,  2 , 1) == "2"
```

---

```
      mawk1 | substr($0, -1 , 2) == "123"              mawk1 | substr($0,  2 , 2) == "23"
      mawk2 | substr($0, -1 , 2) == ""                 mawk2 | substr($0,  2 , 2) == "23"
    gawk -e | substr($0, -1 , 2) == "12"             gawk -e | substr($0,  2 , 2) == "23"
   gawk -Pe | substr($0, -1 , 2) == "12"            gawk -Pe | substr($0,  2 , 2) == "23"
   gawk -ce | substr($0, -1 , 2) == "12"            gawk -ce | substr($0,  2 , 2) == "23"
       nawk | substr($0, -1 , 2) == "12"                nawk | substr($0,  2 , 2) == "23"
```

---

```
      mawk1 | substr($0, -1 , 3) == "1234"             mawk1 | substr($0,  2 , 3) == "234"
      mawk2 | substr($0, -1 , 3) == "1"                mawk2 | substr($0,  2 , 3) == "234"
    gawk -e | substr($0, -1 , 3) == "123"            gawk -e | substr($0,  2 , 3) == "234"
   gawk -Pe | substr($0, -1 , 3) == "123"           gawk -Pe | substr($0,  2 , 3) == "234"
   gawk -ce | substr($0, -1 , 3) == "123"           gawk -ce | substr($0,  2 , 3) == "234"
       nawk | substr($0, -1 , 3) == "123"               nawk | substr($0,  2 , 3) == "234"
```

---

```
      mawk1 | substr($0, -1 , 4) == "12345"            mawk1 | substr($0,  2 , 4) == "2345"
      mawk2 | substr($0, -1 , 4) == "12"               mawk2 | substr($0,  2 , 4) == "2345"
    gawk -e | substr($0, -1 , 4) == "1234"           gawk -e | substr($0,  2 , 4) == "2345"
   gawk -Pe | substr($0, -1 , 4) == "1234"          gawk -Pe | substr($0,  2 , 4) == "2345"
   gawk -ce | substr($0, -1 , 4) == "1234"          gawk -ce | substr($0,  2 , 4) == "2345"
       nawk | substr($0, -1 , 4) == "1234"              nawk | substr($0,  2 , 4) == "2345"
```

---

```
      mawk1 | substr($0, -1 , 5) == "123456"           mawk1 | substr($0,  2 , 5) == "23456"
      mawk2 | substr($0, -1 , 5) == "123"              mawk2 | substr($0,  2 , 5) == "23456"
    gawk -e | substr($0, -1 , 5) == "12345"          gawk -e | substr($0,  2 , 5) == "23456"
   gawk -Pe | substr($0, -1 , 5) == "12345"         gawk -Pe | substr($0,  2 , 5) == "23456"
   gawk -ce | substr($0, -1 , 5) == "12345"         gawk -ce | substr($0,  2 , 5) == "23456"
       nawk | substr($0, -1 , 5) == "12345"             nawk | substr($0,  2 , 5) == "23456"
```

---

```
      mawk1 | substr($0, -1 , 6) == "1234567"          mawk1 | substr($0,  2 , 6) == "234567"
      mawk2 | substr($0, -1 , 6) == "1234"             mawk2 | substr($0,  2 , 6) == "234567"
    gawk -e | substr($0, -1 , 6) == "123456"         gawk -e | substr($0,  2 , 6) == "234567"
   gawk -Pe | substr($0, -1 , 6) == "123456"        gawk -Pe | substr($0,  2 , 6) == "234567"
   gawk -ce | substr($0, -1 , 6) == "123456"        gawk -ce | substr($0,  2 , 6) == "234567"
       nawk | substr($0, -1 , 6) == "123456"            nawk | substr($0,  2 , 6) == "234567"
```

---

```
      mawk1 | substr($0, -1 , 7) == "12345678"         mawk1 | substr($0,  2 , 7) == "2345678"
      mawk2 | substr($0, -1 , 7) == "12345"            mawk2 | substr($0,  2 , 7) == "2345678"
    gawk -e | substr($0, -1 , 7) == "1234567"        gawk -e | substr($0,  2 , 7) == "2345678"
   gawk -Pe | substr($0, -1 , 7) == "1234567"       gawk -Pe | substr($0,  2 , 7) == "2345678"
   gawk -ce | substr($0, -1 , 7) == "1234567"       gawk -ce | substr($0,  2 , 7) == "2345678"
       nawk | substr($0, -1 , 7) == "1234567"           nawk | substr($0,  2 , 7) == "2345678"
```

---

```
      mawk1 | substr($0, -1 , 8) == "123456789"        mawk1 | substr($0,  2 , 8) == "23456789"
      mawk2 | substr($0, -1 , 8) == "123456"           mawk2 | substr($0,  2 , 8) == "23456789"
    gawk -e | substr($0, -1 , 8) == "12345678"       gawk -e | substr($0,  2 , 8) == "23456789"
   gawk -Pe | substr($0, -1 , 8) == "12345678"      gawk -Pe | substr($0,  2 , 8) == "23456789"
   gawk -ce | substr($0, -1 , 8) == "12345678"      gawk -ce | substr($0,  2 , 8) == "23456789"
       nawk | substr($0, -1 , 8) == "12345678"          nawk | substr($0,  2 , 8) == "23456789"
```

---

```
      mawk1 | substr($0, -1 , 9) == "123456789"        mawk1 | substr($0,  2 , 9) == "23456789"
      mawk2 | substr($0, -1 , 9) == "1234567"          mawk2 | substr($0,  2 , 9) == "23456789"
    gawk -e | substr($0, -1 , 9) == "123456789"      gawk -e | substr($0,  2 , 9) == "23456789"
   gawk -Pe | substr($0, -1 , 9) == "123456789"     gawk -Pe | substr($0,  2 , 9) == "23456789"
   gawk -ce | substr($0, -1 , 9) == "123456789"     gawk -ce | substr($0,  2 , 9) == "23456789"
       nawk | substr($0, -1 , 9) == "123456789"         nawk | substr($0,  2 , 9) == "23456789"
```

---

```
      mawk1 | substr($0, -1    ) == "123456789"        mawk1 | substr($0,  2    ) == "23456789"
      mawk2 | substr($0, -1    ) == "123456789"        mawk2 | substr($0,  2    ) == "23456789"
    gawk -e | substr($0, -1    ) == "123456789"      gawk -e | substr($0,  2    ) == "23456789"
   gawk -Pe | substr($0, -1    ) == "123456789"     gawk -Pe | substr($0,  2    ) == "23456789"
   gawk -ce | substr($0, -1    ) == "123456789"     gawk -ce | substr($0,  2    ) == "23456789"
       nawk | substr($0, -1    ) == "123456789"         nawk | substr($0,  2    ) == "23456789"
```